# Um fino, um príncipe, um imperial, ou uma tulipa?

Tags: significado-em-contexto, vocabulário, diferenças-transatlânticas

Se eu quiser beber um copo de chop em Portugal, e solicitar "um príncipe", "um fino", ou "uma imperial", qual o volume exato de chop que me será servido? Uma tulipa também é um termo usado?

Comment: Vou abrir uma pergunta a perguntar o que é um chop. :p

Comment: Cerveja de pressão deve ser a mesma coisa que chop.

Comment: Uma imperial e não um imperial

Answer (score 5):

Um fino e uma imperial são a mesma coisa.
A palavra fino é gíria do norte, a imperial do centro e sul.

É tudo cerveja de pressão servida em copo:

- Fino/imperial: 20cl, [copo alto esguio](https://store.superbock.pt/pt/pt/copo-super-bock-original-6-copos-20cl).
- Lambreta: 15cl, copo médio esguio.
- Príncipe: 33cl, semelhante a um fino mas mais alto.
- Caneca: 50cl (até 1L?), caneca larga com asa.
- Tulipa: 20cl? 33cl?, copo curvo (em forma de tulipa) que se diz ser mais próprio para beber cerveja.

Os copos de tulipa variam muito de sítio para sítio.
Não sei se há um formato padrão.
O volume também parece variar.

---

Menção honrosa aos primos:

- Um *tango* é uma cerveja traçada com groselha.
- Um *panaché* é uma cerveja traçada com 7Up.
- Uma *diesel* é uma cerveja traçada com coca-cola...

Comment: Interessante, nós usamos mililitros ao invés de centilitros.

Comment: E "um príncipe"?

Comment: É um filho de um rei, @Centaurus . 

Comment: Obrigado pelo reparo, já expandi a resposta. Levas tango/panaché/diesel como juros de mora. :)

Comment: Com 7Up ou com o que os franceses chaman de *limonade*?? Mélange de bière et de limonade.

Comment: @Lambie, em Portugal é com 7Up ou equivalente. Como o tango e o diesel (bleh), o panaché é uma bebida de café/bar comum, onde não há limonadas.

Comment: @ANeves A palavra limonade **em frances** não é bem limonada (água e limão fresco). Eu sei muito bem  o que é panaché. Morei na França 16 anos e essa bebida vem de lá.

Comment: Mas o tuga não é capaz de evitar o seu toque de midas  culinário - seja no panaché, seja no croque monsieur (-> francesinha), seja no [croissant](https://www.mondomulia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Porto-Croissants-1.jpg), seja na bola de berlim. HAH, bolas de berlim recheadas de compota em vez de creme de pasteleiro... que tolos os alemães!

Comment: Pois é. Aí tem o fulano que entrou num café em Portugal e pediu um latte. A senhora que estava servindo respondeu: café em lata? Não conheço. Nem me lembro aonde ouvi essa história.

Comment: Hahaha, ri-me como um perdido com essa história... :D Coincidência ou não, o único café de lata que conheço é japonês (Suntory Boss coffee), e os anúncios antigos dele são bem ao estilo dessa história: "[BOSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lv2l1JKuxxY)".

Comment: Pelo menos no Rio Grande do Sul, Pé Sujo é cerveja com coca-cola.